# Node and npm too slow to start after install of macOS Mojave

Tags: angularjs, node.js, macos-mojave

Actually, before macOS Mojave, node/npm would start immediately, and then depending on the task would take their time (10-20 seconds to finish ng start ).

After upgrading to macOS Mojave, it takes 30-45 seconds to start the process, then 10-20 seconds to ng serve.

The only change was upgrading to macOS Mojave

Any ideas?

Comment: is spotlight bogging down system by indexing code / outputs / bundles which is should be told to ignore ?

Comment: from a terminal issue `top` to view what is consuming CPU ... dunno osx however on linux there are other resource usage viewers like iotop etc.. which will suggest what is consuming either cpu or IO from disk or bandwidth

Comment: All other systems seem to be working fine, including spotlight. With top, I see npm starting, but no reason why it takes longer to get actually perdorm the job.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue...

Again Issue was not just related to Angular or React project... 
All the nodejs based CLI got slower after macOS Mojave update.

I had nvm to manage my node version so install LTS again with `nvm install --lts`
and `npm start` and `ng start` starts working normally ...

If you do not have `nvm` just remove nodejs and reinstall again

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall node using node version manager.
https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but with different programming languages. The issue appears for some network related things, e.g. slows down tests.

Could you please try the following:

- ensure that localhost is present in /etc/hosts
- add your mac hostname to /etc/hosts as "127.0.0.1 yourhostname"

By the end it should look like

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 yourhostname

255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```